# Where is the Content Manager in 8.2

Tags: content-editor

In Sitecore 7.2 I was setting the content editor context language in code:

```
public class DefaultLanguageContentEditorForm : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentEditorDataContext.Language = Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.DefaultLanguage;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

In 8.2, stuff has moved. Where is `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm`? Can I even access it this way anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ContentEditorForm` is still located in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager` in the latest version of Sitecore.

Make sure you have referenced the `Sitecore.Client` assembly correctly:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can search for stuff like that online? Or am I stuck with DotPeek-ing into multiple DLLs?

Comment: dotPeek is a Sitecore devs best friend :) Also you don't need to do 1 assembly at a time, you can add an entire bin folder in and then hit `ctrl-t` to find a class.